# Merging lines in a file to correspond with a given header

Tags: java, arrays, file, bufferedreader

I have a file which contains a series of headers followed by a description of the header in one or multiple lines. Something like:

```
>Animal|Dog
this is a dog
which barks
>Animal|Cat
Cats often meow
>Animal|Bat
Bat will fly
and comes out at night
eating small insects
```

Im trying to merge elements of the file such that each description is put into a single line and corresponds to its given header. Like:

```
Animals = [Dog,this is a dog which barks],[Cat,Cats often meow],[Bat,Bat will fly and come out at night eating small insects]
```

Im unsure how to accomplish this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("speciesFile.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(">")) {

                String[] array = line.split("|");
                if(array.length == 2){
                    String name = array[1];
                    // add to array
                }
            }else{
                // line is description
                // check if line below is description and merge
                // add to array
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This looks like an exercise on arrays. You should create one and add stuff to it like it says in those comments. Assuming you are in some course, check the materials you have about arrays or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: @zapl its part of a larger program im working on, the above would be a simplified version of what im working on.

Comment: What are you unsure about? The comments sound reasonable. Why didn't you implement that?

Comment: @zapl I must be missing something, which comments are you referring to?

Comment: Those in your source code, `// check if line below is description and merge`.

Comment: ah yes, im unsure how to implement those, how would I check if there is a next line, if line.next !contain < merged line = line1 + line2? and how do I add these into the appropriate field of the array to correspond to the header above them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish this. Instead of an array, I'm using an `ArrayList` and I've created a simple model object called `Animal` to contain each animal record.

See the comments in the code for more details.

```
public class MergeLines
{
    // Animal model object:
    // Note: This can placed in another file called Animal.java and
    // made into a public, non-static class, but I created it in this
    // manner for purpose of having a and self-containted example.
    private static class Animal
    {
        private String name;
        private String description;

        public Animal(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description)
        {
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString ()
        {
            return "[" + name + "," + description + "]";
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // this list will hold our animals
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("speciesFile.txt")))
        {
            String line;
            String description = "";
            Animal animal = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.contains(">"))
                {
                    // check if we had a previous animal
                    if (description.length() > 0 && animal != null)
                    {
                        // set the description and add to the list
                        animal.setDescription(description);
                        animals.add(animal);

                        // reset for the next animal
                        description = "";
                        animal = null;
                    }

                    // Note: you had split("|") but that is incorrect 
                    // since the '|' character means OR in regex.
                    String[] array = line.split("\\|");
                    if (array.length == 2)
                    {
                        String name = array[1];

                        // create the animal
                        animal = new Animal(name);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    description = description + " " + line;
                }
            }

            // add the last animal to the list
            if (animal != null)
            {
                animal.setDescription(description);
                animals.add(animal);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // finally, print them out.
        System.out.println("Animals = " + animals);
    }
}
```

**Outputs**:

> Animals = [[Dog, this is a dog which barks], [Cat, Cats often meow],
>   [Bat, Bat will fly and comes out at night eating small insects]]